# How to calculate variance for distinct value in a vector in r?

Tags: r, variance

I have a vector named p1 and p1 has distinct values. I want to calculate the variance of each  values in p1 and store the information in p2.

my code does not work, it only returns a single variance

```
p1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10)
p2 = 

p2 <- unlist(foreach(i =2:length(p1) %do% var(p1)
```

Comment: I want to compute the variance in from the 2nd value in P1 to the last value in P1. and return a list of variances

Comment: The variance of *one*  value is zero. Do you want the variance from 2:length(p1), then 3:length(p1), etc?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do

Comment: `sapply(2:length(p1), \(i) var(p1[i:length(p1)]))`.